# Dovecot error accessing /tmp/ on 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, dovecot

I've run into a problem, which I don't entirely understand. Occasionally I get this line in `/var/mail.err`, although all messages seem to be saved normally (at least I think so):

```
dovecot: lda(<address>): Error: safe_mkstemp(/tmp/dovecot.lda.) failed: Permission denied
```

I understand that this permission can be adjusted manually, but I worry that something might have gone wrong with the system itself.

The only result that I could google is this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=632951, which says that it is a bug...

Some additional info:

```
# uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# dovecot --version
2.2.9
```

I don't know if that matters, but I am also running the system on RAID1, and it was a very fresh install of the new version of ubuntu.

I would appreciate any comments or suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste the permissions: `ls -ld /tmp`. Also if there is enough space: `df -h /tmp`. Then also check if you find any entries in `/var/log/kern.log` around similar time.

Edit: the issue turned out that the permissions of /tmp were somehow messed up. Correcting with `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This is the output `# ls -ld /tmp`
`drwxr-xr-t 3 root root 4096 Jul 15 21:17 /tmp`
`# df -h /tmp`
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on` `/dev/md1        3.7G  7.5M  3.4G   1% /tmp` and there is nothing interesting in kern.log around these times, only ufw block events

Comment: So the problem is that /tmp permissions have somehow been messed up. It should show "drwxrwxrwt'. You can correct with "sudo chmod 1777 /tmp". This is likely to cause other major problems and not just in dovecot. Also check /var/tmp which should also show 'drwxrwxrwt'. As you mention, this could point to some other activity which went wrong and messed up /tmp and possibly other things. You might want to look closely at /var/log/auth.log, /var/log/syslog for suspicious activity when dovecot first started showing these errors.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've changed permissions, but I absolutely do not see any other suspicious entries in other logs... anyway this is now working, I suppose, also /var/tmp had the correct permissions set... Can you update your answer so that it says that permissions should be 1777 please?